# How to filter data taken from html in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm, loops, filtering

I'm trying to get data from a boxing site and build a JSON with that information. I managed to get the divs I need, but I can't filter correctly.

```
    const scheduleBoxingScene = "https://www.boxingscene.com/schedule";
    axios(scheduleBoxingScene).then((response) => {
    const html = response.data;
    const selector = cheerio.load(html);
    const searchResults = selector("body")
    .find(".body-container > .schedule > div")
    .toString()
    .replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ')

    console.log(searchResults)
```

I tried using text() function instead of toString() but sometimes there are texts that I don't need, so I prefer to get the texts I need through the html classes.

For example, i need the text inside of `<div class="fight-date"> </div>`, but there's 20 div classes fight-date in my searchResults, how do i take each one of them?

Comment: access `https://www.boxingscene.com/schedule` then run `[...document.querySelectorAll('.schedule div.fight-date')].map(item => item.textContent)` in your browser console.